# Запуск несколько одинаковых приложений

Tags: windows, windows-10, visual-basic, autohotkey, autoit

Подскажите, почему не работает? Искал, но не нашел, как запустить несколько одинаковых приложений, что бы потом можно было с каждым отдельно работать.
Скрипт работает, запускает первое окно, перемещает его, потом второе запускается и первое перемещается по координатном второго, а второго не двигается. В чем косяк?

```
Run('c:\Program Files\CPUID\CPU-Z\cpuz.exe')
$hWnd = WinWait("[TITLE:CPU-Z; INSTANCE:1]", "", 0)
If Not $hWnd Then
    MsgBox(4096, 'Сообщение', 'Окно не найдено, завершаем работу скрипта')
    Exit
EndIf
Sleep(400)
WinMove($hWnd, "", 0, 645)

Run('c:\Program Files\CPUID\CPU-Z\cpuz.exe')
$hWnd2 = WinWaitActive("[TITLE:CPU-Z; INSTANCE:2]", "", 0)
If Not $hWnd2 Then
    MsgBox(4096, 'Сообщение', 'Окно не найдено, завершаем работу скрипта')
    Exit
EndIf
Sleep(400)
WinMove($hWnd2, "", 405, 645)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы неправильно получаете hwnd второго окна. Надежнее ориентироваться на PID процесса. Попробуйте так:

```
$pid1 = Run('c:\Program Files\CPUID\CPU-Z\cpuz.exe')
WinWait("[TITLE:CPU-Z; INSTANCE:1]", "", 0)
$hWnd = _GetHwndFromPID($pid1)

If Not $hWnd Then
    MsgBox(4096, 'Сообщение', 'Окно не найдено, завершаем работу скрипта')
    Exit
EndIf
Sleep(400)
WinMove($hWnd, "", 0, 645)

$pid2 = Run('c:\Program Files\CPUID\CPU-Z\cpuz.exe')
WinWaitActive("[TITLE:CPU-Z; INSTANCE:2]", "", 0)
$hWnd2 = _GetHwndFromPID($pid2)
If Not $hWnd2 Then
    MsgBox(4096, 'Сообщение', 'Окно не найдено, завершаем работу скрипта')
    Exit
EndIf
Sleep(400)
WinMove($hWnd2, "", 405, 645)

;Function for getting HWND from PID
Func _GetHwndFromPID($PID)
    $hWnd = 0
    $winlist = WinList()
    Do
        For $i = 1 To $winlist[0][0]
            If $winlist[$i][0] <> "" Then
                $iPID2 = WinGetProcess($winlist[$i][1])
                If $iPID2 = $PID Then
                    $hWnd = $winlist[$i][1]
                    ExitLoop
                EndIf
            EndIf
        Next
    Until $hWnd <> 0
    Return $hWnd
EndFunc;==>_GetHwndFromPID
```

Comment: У меня не работает, https://i.imgur.com/9uzwoHW.png

Comment: Вероятно, дело в версии Autoit. Я запускаю в Autoit v3.3.14.2

Comment: все работает, я просто по ошибке компилировал в Ahk. Сразу назрел вопрос, как можно будет изменить код что бы к примеру обрабатывало не два окна а более, три, четыре...?

Comment: Просто транслируем кусок кода нужное количество раз: получить pid -> получить по pid hwnd -> двигать окно по hwnd. Либо написать функцию.